# Make these elements be inline / in one single line via CSS

Tags: html, css, joomla

a module in my Joomla CMS produces the following code:

```
<li id="myid" clas="">
   <span>
      <strong>1.</strong>
   </span>

   <dl>
      <dt>
         <span>Some text</span>
      </dt>
  </dl>
</li>
```

This must not be edited in html, since it is created via multiple plugins.
Is there a way to make "Some text" appear on the right of "1." via CSS. I tried something like:

```
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

which didnt work. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the `dl` and `dt` to display as `inline`, because their default is `block`:

```
#myid dl, #myid dt {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Here's it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/XjcAc/ In other words, accept this guy's answer. ;)

Comment: This does not work. If I use this the "Some text" block still gets printed below the the "1"

Comment: @kameltreiber: Can you link to a page showing this not working? There's probably something you haven't told me, because my answer works with the HTML you provided.

Comment: You can find the page on: http://bit.ly/egvCOD  You can see the problems at the tabs. I have enabled the plugin, so that you can see the error. Please tell me when done, so that I can disable the plugin again.

Comment: Insert into the relevant place in your CSS: `ul.gk_tab_ul-style1 li { white-space: nowrap; margin-right: 47px; }` and `ul.gk_tab_ul-style1 li span { display: inline; }`. The backgrounds are a bit screwed up though. The easiest solution is to simply remove them with `#tabmix1 ul * { background: none; }`.

Comment: Thanks, now the texts gets visible - but still below the 1. and not in the right of it. I think wer are very close...

Comment: What I posted before only worked in Chrome/Safari, which is where I tested it. It's not working in other browsers because you still need the original fix from my answer (I thought you had it already), which for your HTML is this: `ul.gk_tab_ul-style1 li dl, ul.gk_tab_ul-style1 li dt { display: inline; }`.

Comment: All right this works now - but now I do not like the style. I would really like to have the background and the textstyle as I like it. At least I can do something abouzt the textstyle by myself. But the background is the problem now. I just disable the plugin so that you can see the original that works, but produces unclean html code.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to hack the original and change the outer `span` to a `div` to make it valid HTML?

Comment: Proboably. Let me tell you about the problem: The module inserted is the Jommla: gavicks tab module. If you check the site by the w3c-html-validator the code is not correcty, what is bad e.g. for SEO. I checked the whole module folder in the Joomla-directory but couldnt finde aps <span> that reffers to that one in the code (tried by removing all spans in the code files). The next approach was to use the tidy-html-plugin. This plugin cleans the code and makes it wellformed. This is great, but the result is that the tab text is below the number then. See also: http://bit.ly/zRoTyl

Comment: @kameltreiber: This is veering wildly away from the original question. I can't be bothered making an account on the Gavick site to be able to download the plugin you're using to search through the files to be able to tell you which `<span>` to change. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ordered list instead unordered list? It can be simplified..

But if yout want go with your code you must delete "" tag from list number, cause it would be deprecated. Solution is add class='strong' in your  tag for your number and add more css, here's the code for 'strong' class :

```
#myid .strong{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Your html code :

```
<li id="myid" clas="">
   <span class="strong">1.</span><dl>
      <dt>
         <span>Some text</span>
      </dt>
  </dl>
</li>
```

Comment: Actually I can not inserts code like "strong" into the html code.